# Instantiate Python unittest.TestCase with arguments

Tags: python-2.7, arguments, test-suite, python-unittest

I would like to iterate over a list of items, and run an assertion on each of them. One example might be checking whether each number in a list is odd.

`TestCase`:

```
class TestOdd(unittest.TestCase):
    def runTest(self):
        """Assert that the item is odd"""
        self.assertTrue( NUMBER %2==1, "Number should be odd")
```

Test `suite`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest(TestOdd())
    # I would like to have:
    # suite.addTest(TestOdd(1))
    # suite.addTest(TestOdd(2))
    # suite.addTest(TestOdd(3))
    # ...
    unittest.main()
```

How can I instantiate a `TestOdd` object with an argument - for example, the number to be tested?

**Update: According to a blog post from 2011 (posted as answer), there is no built-in mechanism for parametrized tests. I will be happy to accept any cleaner solutions.**

Comment: See also: [Accessing argparse arguments from the class](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/88655/15346) at CR

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Same can be achieved using class attributes.

```
class TestOdd1(unittest.TestCase):
    NUMBER=1
    def runTest(self):
        """Assert that the item is odd"""
        self.assertTrue( self.NUMBER % 2 == 1, "Number should be odd")

class TestOdd2(TestOdd1):
    NUMBER=2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The unittesting will discover them automatically, so no need to create a suite.

If you want to avoid using a TestCase for base class, you can use multiple inheritance:

```
from unittest import TestCase, main

class TestOdd:
    def runTest(self):
        """Assert that the item is odd"""
        self.assertTrue( self.NUMBER % 2 == 1, "Number should be odd")

class TestOdd1(TestOdd, TestCase):
    NUMBER=1
class TestOdd2(TestOdd, TestCase):
    NUMBER=2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 14):

According to "[Python unit testing: parametrized test cases](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/08/02/python-unit-testing-parametrized-test-cases/)", published in Eli Bendersky's blog:

> Python’s standard unittest library is great and I use it all the time.
>   One thing missing from it, however, is a simple way of running
>   parametrized test cases. In other words, you can’t easily pass
>   arguments into a unittest.TestCase from outside.

Eli's solution is inheriting `unittest.TestCase` into `ParametrizedTestCase`. I'm not sure about copyright issues, so I won't copy-paste the code here.

If there is any better solution, I will be happy to accept it.

Comment: In 2018, Eli Bendersky's blog is still the best way to achieve this.

Comment: This is interesting, but seems limited by the fact that you can't have more than one `param` per `TestCase` without changing the init signature

Answer (score 0):

I would go this way:

`TestCase` file containing test logic itself:

```
import my_config
from unittest import TestCase

class TestOdd(unittest.TestCase):
    def runTest(self):
        """Assert that the item is odd"""
        self.assertTrue(int(my_config.options['number']) %2==1, "Number should be odd")
```

then in the `TestSuite` file:

```
import argparse
import my_config
import TestCase

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-num', '--number', type=int, default=0)
    my_config.options = parser.parse_args()
    
    suite_case = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestCase)
    test_suite = unittest.TestSuite([suite_case])

    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=1, failfast=True, buffer=False).run(test_suite)
```

`my_config.py` helping file:

```
options = {}
```

and then from command line we can execute:

```
python3 -m unittest TestSuite.py --number=1
python3 -m unittest TestSuite.py --number=2
.
.
python3 -m unittest TestSuite.py --number=1000
```

Or execution calling from command line could be done by using *`for`* cycle inside Shell script.